# Subgroup $Q$ of $M\times M'$ is not a direct product of subgroups of $M$ & $M'$, do $M$ and $M'$ share no simple subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

Let $M$ and $M'$ be groups.
Let $M\times M'$ be a direct product.
If a subgroup $Q$ of $M\times M'$ is not a direct product of subgroups of $M$ and $M'$,
in other words, $Q\neq \{(m,m') \mid m\in P\le M \text{ and } m'\in P'\le M'\})$,
can we say that $M$ and $M'$ share no simple subgroups?
In other words, for every simple subgroup $S$ of $M$ and simple subgroup $S'$ of $M'$, $S$ is not isomorphic to $S'$.

Comment: The diagonal subgroup of $M$x$M$ is not a direct product of subgroups.

Comment: I added some clarification to how the question was posed.

Comment: I don't understand the clarification.

Comment: All right, I have further fleshed out the question to create more clarification.

Comment: True, the diagonal subgroup is not a direct product of subgroups.

Comment: Well, since the diagonal subgroup is not a direct product of subgroups it follows that your claim is false (as $M$ and $M$ can share simple subgroups).

Comment: The M and M' in my question are two different groups.

Comment: That was not specified.  Anyway, it's irrelevant.  Take $M'=MxG$ where $G$ is whatever group you like.  Then embed $M$ into $MxM'$ as $m\rightarrow \{m,m,e\}$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1506804/disjoint-simple-subgroups-when-direct-product-has-special-subgroups

Comment: I'm not following you. You appear to be defining M', which is an arbitrary group that is given to us. Also, do you mean for your $x$ to indicate a variable, or are you creating the direct product MxG?

Comment: I have given an example of a direct product ($M$x($M$x$G$)) which has a subgroup which is not a direct product of subgroups of the factors, yet the factors obviously can contain simple subgroups in common.  That counterexample disproves your claim.  If you meant something different, you need to explain yourself more clearly.

Comment: From the question, we are given 2 arbitrary groups, and a subgroup formed from the direct product of these two arbitrary groups. However, we are told that this new subgroup is not itself a direct product of subgroups of the two arbitrary groups M,M'. However, this does not mean that we can ignore the elements of either of the original arbitrary groups, as they appear in the subgroup. If I'm reading your construction correctly, you seem to be eliminating elements from one of the original arbitrary groups.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand why my example isn't a counterexample to your general claim.  Perhaps someone else can.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It has been carefully explained in the comments that the answer to your question is no, we cannot say that share no simple subgroups. Let me try again.

Suppose that $M=\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{p-1}\}$ and $M' = \{ 1,y,y^2,\ldots,y^{p-1}\}$ are both cyclic groups of order $p$. So $M$ and $M'$ are isomorphic simple groups, and hence they "share simple subgroups". Do you agree, or do you mean something different by "share simple subgroups"?

Anyway $M \times M'$ has the subgroup $Q=\{ (x^i,y^i) \mid 0 \le i \le p-1 \}$ which is not a direct product of subgroups of $M$ and $M'$.

I think you have got the question wrong. What is true is that if *all* subgroups of $M \times M'$ are of the form $N \times N'$ with $N \le M$ and $N' \le M'$ (i.e. if there are NO subgroups $Q$ of the type you describe), then $M$ and $N$ share no simple subgroups.